# Kubelet config file -- > clusterDNS

Tags: kubernetes, networking, kubectl, network-monitoring

clusterDNS:

### - "10.32.0.10"

The above is a flag passed to the kubelet file, i dont know what it refers to clsuter DNS ? Is it refers to VPC CIDR or any subnet CIDR ?

Comment: any help would really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It is the address of the DNS server (probably CoreDNS but possibly kube-dns) for the cluster.

Kubernetes uses a DNS server within the cluster so pods can find each other using service names. This is the "cluster DNS" server. Every time a service is created, it gets registered in the DNS server.

In Linux, the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is where the DNS server is configured. If you want to use Google's public DNS server (8.8.8.8) your `/etc/resolv.conf` file has the entry `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.

In Kubernetes, the kubelet process on a worker node configures each pod.  Part of the configuration process is to create the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and specify the correct DNS server.  That server is spec'ed by the `clusterDNS` configuration option.

How you set it (if you even *need* to set it yourself) depends on how you're installing kubernetes.  It ultimately depends on the CNI provider you're using, but also if you're doing "kubernetes the hard way" versus `kubeadm`.

Comment: is it a default one ? or we should provide it with the vpc cidr ?

Comment: where is it coming from?  Are you following a tutorial or looking at an existing installation, or what?

Comment: @Matthew please add more details

Comment: Hey Mathew,  i am following a tutorial (linux academy) "kubernetes the hard way". there when creating the configuration file for kubelet and kube-proxy config files , a flag with cidr is mentioned and provided a value but my point is can i blindly take that value from the tutorial or i should change according to my vpc cidr ?

Comment: It depends on which networking provider you go with.  Weave uses the 10.32.0.0/12 network by default. If you're going to use weave, keep it as is.  If you're using a different one, read their documentation.